# how to see PostgreSQLContainer database records

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have created PostgreSQLContainer as below

```
public static PostgreSQLContainer postgres = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres")
        .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withName("postgres-sql"))
        .withNetworkAliases("postgres")
        .withStartupTimeoutSeconds(240)
        .withConnectTimeoutSeconds(240)
        .withNetwork(componentTestNetwork)
        .withFileSystemBind(pathToFile + "/postgres/", "/postgres", BindMode.READ_WRITE)
        .withExposedPorts(5432)
        .withStartupAttempts(10)
        .withInitScript("postgres/create_table.sql")
        .waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck());
```

Content of create_table.sql  is as below:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS techwriting;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS techwriting.book(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
description varchar(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT book_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));


INSERT INTO techwriting.book (id,name,description) VALUES
(1,'premchand','classical');
INSERT INTO techwriting.book (id,name,description) VALUES
(2,'nirala','horror');
INSERT INTO techwriting.book (id,name,description) VALUES
(3,'premchand','horror');
INSERT INTO techwriting.book (id,name,description) VALUES
(4,'premchand','xyz');
```

My Docker Desktop is up and I can see container for postgresql is created. Now I wanted to see the records that have been inserted from create_table.sql but I am not able to see them. How and where to find those records?

The only thing I found on Docker Desktop is volume for postgresql container. Which has certain info related to postgresql . I have attached here for reference. But again I am not able to see records which got inserted from
create_table.sql  .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can [publish ports via testcotnainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/256). Then you can connect to the database using some client. I prefer to do it via `psql` (or you can set up a temporary connection using `pgAdmin`), it comes with most postgres distributions:

```
psql --host=localhost --port=<port_you_have_published> --username=<username> --dbname=<your_db_name> --password
```

and then you good to go, just select the stuff you want :)

Comment: I  got the answer . We can connect using pgAdmin  For that we need  host name, port  , username,  password & db value. We can get host & port value using PostgreSQLContainer.getHost()   &  PostgreSQLContainer.getFirstMappedPort() .  Also for TestContainer default value of db , username & password is "test".  With these set of values I was able to see records.